# Customizing Selector when another another Selector value changes

Tags: acumatica

I need to Customize CaseClassID Selector on Cases Screen. It should refresh with different values when Contract field is selected on the CaseScreen under the Additional Info tab. Right now the CaseClass is displaying values from CRCase table.But, now if the contract changes the fieldupdatedEvent should be triggered and CaseClassID selector should have values accordingly. Please suggest me how to customize the CaseClassID selector inside FieldUpdated Event Handler

```
protected virtual void CRCase_ContractID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, 
      PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        CRCase cc = (CRCase)e.Row;
        if (cc == null) return;
        CRCase_CaseClassID_CacheAttached(sender);
    }

[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa")]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<CRSetup.defaultCaseClassID>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Class ID")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<CRCaseClass.caseClassID, 
         InnerJoin<CaseContract, On<CaseContract.caseClassID, 
            Equal<CRCaseClass.caseClassID>>,
        InnerJoin<Contract, On<CaseContract.contractID, 
            Equal<Contract.templateID>>,
        InnerJoin<CRCase, On<Contract.contractID, 
            Equal<Current<CRCase.contractID>>>>>>,
        Where<CaseContract.active, Equal<True>>>),
               DescriptionField = typeof(CRCaseClass.description),
               CacheGlobal = true)]
    [PXMassUpdatableField]
    public virtual String CaseClassID { get; set; }
    public virtual void CRCase_CaseClassID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender){

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override CaseClassID selector and add your custom logic in its type parameter.
You can create a custom unbound field to filter the selector according to your business logic. When you want to change selector filter, just change the custom field.

```
#region CaseClassID
public abstract class caseClassID : IBqlField { }

[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa")]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<CRSetup.defaultCaseClassID>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Class ID")]
// Use your custom field (filterCaseClassID) in the selector type parameter
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CRCaseClass.caseClassID,
                   Where<CRCaseClass.caseClassID, Equal<filterCaseClassID>>>),
                   DescriptionField = typeof(CRCaseClass.description), 
                   CacheGlobal = true)]
[PXMassUpdatableField]
public virtual String CaseClassID { get; set; }
#endregion

#region FilterCaseClassID
public abstract class filterCaseClassID : IBqlField { }

[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa")]
// Change the value of your custom field to set the selector filter
public virtual String FilterCaseClassID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

**EDIT overriding DAC field in graph extension and filtering Selector by using a field from another DAC:**

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR.MassProcess;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.CR
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CaseContract : IBqlTable
    {
        public abstract class caseClassID : IBqlField { }

        [PXString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Case Class ID")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(CRCaseClass.caseClassID),
                    DescriptionField = typeof(CRCaseClass.description))]
        public virtual String CaseClassID
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    public class CRCaseMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
    {
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
        [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa")]
        [PXDefault(typeof(Search<CRSetup.defaultCaseClassID>))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Class ID")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<CRCaseClass.caseClassID,
                           Where<Current<CaseContract.caseClassID>, IsNull,
                           Or<CRCaseClass.caseClassID, Equal<Current<CaseContract.caseClassID>>>>>),
                    DescriptionField = typeof(CRCaseClass.description),
                    CacheGlobal = true)]
        [PXMassUpdatableField]
        public virtual void CRCase_CaseClassID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to dynamically change one selector values based on another Selector.i.e, If the second Selector is updated with a value then I should get data from database accordingly and display in the first selector

Comment: I misunderstood your question so I have edited my answer.

Comment: You can override it in the graph extension using CacheAttached event handler. public virtual void CRCase _CaseClassID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender). When you override it, you can specify a new query that includes your logic in the type parameter.

Comment: I edited answer to add CacheAttached DAC field override example.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation. I am not clear on how to get the current selected ContractID in Contract Selector to filter the CaseClasses to display in Class ID Selector. Please help me with this!

Comment: I edited my question providing the code I have written. I am calling the CacheAttached event inside FieldUpdated event of ContractID. The FiledUpdated event is triggering but the values for Class ID selector is not changing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163062/discussion-between-prathyu-and-hb-acumatica).

Comment: Thank you! @HB_Acumatica your sample code worked perfectly!